# Can't route Strongswan VPN Traffic through AWS Internet Gateway

Tags: amazon-ec2, vpn, ipsec, amazon-vpc, strongswan

Cheers, I want to setup a VPN Server on an EC2 Instance in order to route all my private internet traffic, but I can't get it to work. Any help would be appreciated.

I have the following Setup:

```
    Private Network  10.0.0.0/24    |               Internet              |  AWS VPC / Subnet 10.0.1.0/24
   PC                        Fritzbox Router                             IGW         EC2
 10.0.0.11   ----    10.0.0.1 ------| -- MyPublicLocalIP -- EC2PublicIP --| ------ 10.0.1.193
```

The Router has an IPSec Connection to a Strongswan instance running on the EC2 Instance.
The Network Interface of the EC2 Instance has Source/Dest Checking disabled.
The Security Group allows incoming all traffic with source from PublicLocalIP and from the subnet (also tried "allow all sources") and destination any.

The VPN Connection can be established and I can ping 10.0.1.142 and 10.0.1.1 from my private network.
The EC2 instance itself can also ping public IPs like 8.8.8.8.
But I can't ping 8.8.8.8 or any other public IP from my private network even though I can see the packets going in one direction on the EC2 Instance with tshark:

tshark -f "icmp"

```
   10 7.320371756    10.0.0.11 → 8.8.8.8      ICMP 98 Echo (ping) request  id=0x0034, seq=1/256, ttl=63
   11 8.332639368    10.0.0.11 → 8.8.8.8      ICMP 98 Echo (ping) request  id=0x0034, seq=2/512, ttl=63
   12 9.356457465    10.0.0.11 → 8.8.8.8      ICMP 98 Echo (ping) request  id=0x0034, seq=3/768, ttl=63
   13 10.380464177    10.0.0.11 → 8.8.8.8      ICMP 98 Echo (ping) request  id=0x0034, seq=4/1024, ttl=63
   14 11.404715789    10.0.0.11 → 8.8.8.8      ICMP 98 Echo (ping) request  id=0x0034, seq=5/1280, ttl=63
   15 12.428989444    10.0.0.11 → 8.8.8.8      ICMP 98 Echo (ping) request  id=0x0034, seq=6/1536, ttl=63
```

This is the EC2 ipsec.conf

```
config setup
conn %default
 type=tunnel
 left=%any
 leftid=EC2PublicIP
 leftsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
 auto=add
 fragmentation=yes
 forceencaps=no
 mobike=yes
 leftauth=psk
 rightauth=psk

conn fb
 ike=aes256-sha-modp1024
 esp=aes256-sha1-modp1024
 right=MyPublicLocalFQ.net
 rightid=@MyPublicLocalFQ.net
 rightsubnet=10.0.0.0/24
 rightdns=8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4
 ikelifetime=3600s
 keylife=3600s
```

This is the Fritzbox router IPSec configuration

```
vpncfg {
  connections {
    enabled = no;
    editable = yes;
    conn_type = conntype_lan;
    name = "EC2VPN";
    boxuser_id = 0;
    always_renew = yes;
    reject_not_encrypted = no;
    dont_filter_netbios = yes;
    localip = 0.0.0.0;
    local_virtualip = 0.0.0.0;
    remoteip = 0.0.0.0;
    remote_virtualip = 0.0.0.0;
    keepalive_ip = 0.0.0.0;
    localid {
      fqdn = "MyPublicLocalFQ.net";
    }
    remoteid {
      fqdn = "EC2PublicIP";
    }
    mode = phase1_mode_idp;
    phase1ss = "all/all/all";
    keytype = connkeytype_pre_shared;
    key = "THE_PSK_KEY";
    cert_do_server_auth = no;
    use_nat_t = yes;
    use_xauth = no;
    use_cfgmode = no;
    phase2localid {
      ipnet {
        ipaddr = 10.0.0.0;
        mask = 255.255.255.0;
      }
    }
    phase2remoteid {
      ipnet {
        ipaddr = 10.0.1.0;
        mask = 255.255.255.0;
      }
    }
    phase2ss = "esp-all-all/ah-none/comp-all/pfs";
    accesslist = "permit ip any any";
  }
  ike_forward_rules = "udp 0.0.0.0:500 0.0.0.0:500", 
  "udp 0.0.0.0:4500 0.0.0.0:4500";
}
```

ipsec statusall

```
Status of IKE charon daemon (strongSwan 5.8.2, Linux 5.4.0-1029-aws, x86_64):
  uptime: 91 seconds, since Dec 13 01:57:01 2020
  malloc: sbrk 1622016, mmap 0, used 648096, free 973920
  worker threads: 11 of 16 idle, 5/0/0/0 working, job queue: 0/0/0/0, scheduled: 3
  loaded plugins: charon aesni aes rc2 sha2 sha1 md5 mgf1 random nonce x509 revocation constraints pubkey pkcs1 pkcs7 pkcs8 pkcs12 pgp dnskey sshkey pem openssl fips-prf gmp agent xcbc hmac gcm drbg attr kernel-netlink resolve socket-default connmark stroke updown eap-mschapv2 xauth-generic counters
Listening IP addresses:
  10.0.1.193
Connections:
          fb:  %any...MyPublicLocalFQ  IKEv1/2
          fb:   local:  [EC2PublicIP] uses pre-shared key authentication
          fb:   remote: [MyPublicLocalFQ] uses pre-shared key authentication
          fb:   child:  0.0.0.0/0 === 10.0.0.0/24 TUNNEL
Security Associations (1 up, 0 connecting):
          fb[2]: ESTABLISHED 90 seconds ago, 10.0.1.193[EC2PublicIP]...MyPublicLocalIP[MyPublicLocalFQ]
          fb[2]: IKEv1 SPIs: c1c1ef074becc316_i 3e3007efcc116605_r*, pre-shared key reauthentication in 43 minutes
          fb[2]: IKE proposal: AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA1_96/PRF_HMAC_SHA1/MODP_1024
          fb{1}:  INSTALLED, TUNNEL, reqid 1, ESP in UDP SPIs: cba035a9_i 4fbe83d8_o
          fb{1}:  AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA1_96/MODP_1024, 5610 bytes_i (83 pkts, 74s ago), 840 bytes_o (10 pkts, 74s ago), rekeying in 43 minutes
          fb{1}:   10.0.1.0/24 === 10.0.0.0/24
```

iptables-save

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Sun Dec 13 02:30:39 2020
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [214:19671]
:INPUT ACCEPT [163:15822]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [82:7863]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [82:7863]
-A FORWARD -s 10.0.0.0/24 -o eth0 -p tcp -m policy --dir in --pol ipsec -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -m tcpmss --mss 1361:1536 -j TCPMSS --set-mss 1360
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Dec 13 02:30:39 2020
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Sun Dec 13 02:30:39 2020
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [51:3849]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [4:361]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [4:361]
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/24 -o eth0 -m policy --dir out --pol ipsec -j ACCEPT
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Dec 13 02:30:39 2020
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Sun Dec 13 02:30:39 2020
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:ufw-after-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-after-input - [0:0]
:ufw-after-logging-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-after-logging-input - [0:0]
:ufw-after-logging-output - [0:0]
:ufw-after-output - [0:0]
:ufw-before-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-before-input - [0:0]
:ufw-before-logging-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-before-logging-input - [0:0]
:ufw-before-logging-output - [0:0]
:ufw-before-output - [0:0]
:ufw-logging-allow - [0:0]
:ufw-logging-deny - [0:0]
:ufw-not-local - [0:0]
:ufw-reject-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-reject-input - [0:0]
:ufw-reject-output - [0:0]
:ufw-skip-to-policy-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-skip-to-policy-input - [0:0]
:ufw-skip-to-policy-output - [0:0]
:ufw-track-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-track-input - [0:0]
:ufw-track-output - [0:0]
:ufw-user-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-user-input - [0:0]
:ufw-user-limit - [0:0]
:ufw-user-limit-accept - [0:0]
:ufw-user-logging-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-user-logging-input - [0:0]
:ufw-user-logging-output - [0:0]
:ufw-user-output - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j ufw-before-logging-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-before-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-after-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-after-logging-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-reject-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-track-input
-A FORWARD -j ufw-before-logging-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-before-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-after-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-after-logging-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-reject-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-track-forward
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-before-logging-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-before-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-after-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-after-logging-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-reject-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-track-output
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 137 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 138 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 139 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 445 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -m addrtype --dst-type BROADCAST -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-logging-forward -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
-A ufw-after-logging-input -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
-A ufw-before-forward -s 10.0.0.0/24 -m policy --dir in --pol ipsec --proto esp -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -d 10.0.0.0/24 -m policy --dir out --pol ipsec --proto esp -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 3 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 12 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -j ufw-user-forward
-A ufw-before-input -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j ufw-logging-deny
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 3 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 12 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p udp -m udp --sport 67 --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -j ufw-not-local
-A ufw-before-input -d 224.0.0.251/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 5353 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -d 239.255.255.250/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 1900 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -j ufw-user-input
-A ufw-before-output -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-output -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-output -j ufw-user-output
-A ufw-logging-allow -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "
-A ufw-logging-deny -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j RETURN
-A ufw-logging-deny -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type MULTICAST -j RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type BROADCAST -j RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j ufw-logging-deny
-A ufw-not-local -j DROP
-A ufw-skip-to-policy-forward -j DROP
-A ufw-skip-to-policy-input -j DROP
-A ufw-skip-to-policy-output -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-track-output -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-track-output -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m comment --comment "\'dapp_OpenSSH\'" -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p udp -m multiport --dports 500,4500 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-limit -m limit --limit 3/min -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
-A ufw-user-limit -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A ufw-user-limit-accept -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Dec 13 02:30:39 2020
```

ip route

```
default via 10.0.1.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 10.0.1.193 metric 100
10.0.1.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.1.193
10.0.1.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 10.0.1.193 metric 100
```

The EC2 uses an Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS image.

I also tried adding `rightsourceip=10.10.10.0/24` to ipsec, replacing the pahse2remoteid.ipnet.ipaddr with `ipaddr = 10.10.10.0` replacing all `10.0.0.0/24` in the output of tables-save with `10.10.10.0/24` and using tables-restore, but it still did not work. The Client does not get any VirtualIPs assigned, even tough the pool gets allocated:

```
Status of IKE charon daemon (strongSwan 5.8.2, Linux 5.4.0-1029-aws, x86_64):
  uptime: 32 minutes, since Dec 13 01:09:10 2020
  malloc: sbrk 1622016, mmap 0, used 728048, free 893968
  worker threads: 11 of 16 idle, 5/0/0/0 working, job queue: 0/0/0/0, scheduled: 3
  loaded plugins: charon aesni aes rc2 sha2 sha1 md5 mgf1 random nonce x509 revocation constraints pubkey pkcs1 pkcs7 pkcs8 pkcs12 pgp dnskey sshkey pem openssl fips-prf gmp agent xcbc hmac gcm drbg attr kernel-netlink resolve socket-default connmark stroke updown eap-mschapv2 xauth-generic counters
Virtual IP pools (size/online/offline):
  10.10.10.0/24: 254/0/0
Listening IP addresses:
  10.0.1.193
Connections:
          fb:  %any...MyPublicLocalFQ.net  IKEv1/2
          fb:   local:  [EC2PublicIP] uses pre-shared key authentication
          fb:   remote: [MyPublicLocalFQ.net] uses pre-shared key authentication
          fb:   child:  0.0.0.0/0 === 10.0.0.0/24 TUNNEL
Routed Connections:
          fb{1}:  ROUTED, TUNNEL, reqid 1
          fb{1}:   0.0.0.0/0 === 10.0.0.0/24
Security Associations (1 up, 0 connecting):
          fb[2]: ESTABLISHED 32 minutes ago, 10.0.1.193[EC2PublicIP]...MyPublicLocalIP[MyPublicLocalFQ.net]
          fb[2]: IKEv1 SPIs: 0da6b7368f560272_i 166b8161eae230c8_r*, pre-shared key reauthentication in 12 minutes
          fb[2]: IKE proposal: AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA1_96/PRF_HMAC_SHA1/MODP_1024
          fb{2}:  INSTALLED, TUNNEL, reqid 2, ESP in UDP SPIs: cda4bbc0_i 1ea590b2_o
          fb{2}:  AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA1_96/MODP_1024, 170072 bytes_i (2601 pkts, 26s ago), 1344 bytes_o (16 pkts, 26s ago), rekeying in 12 minutes
          fb{2}:   10.0.1.0/24 === 10.0.0.0/24
```

Any ideas welcome.

Comment: Your traffic selectors only allow traffic between `10.0.1.0/24` and `10.0.0.0/24` through the tunnel (to tunnel all traffic from `10.0.0.0/24`, `10.0.1.0/24` would have to be replaced with `0.0.0.0/0` on both ends, and a NAT will be required on the AWS end to map IPs in `10.0.0.0/24` to a public address). Also, you write something about virtual IPs (_rightsourceip_) but that will only work if the FB actually requests a virtual IP (and you then would have to NAT traffic from `10.0.0.0/24` to that virtual IP on the FB).

Comment: @ecdsa Actually, I wanted to use the EC2 Instance for Nat, hence the postrouting table rules. This is, what my strongswan config looks like now, still not working.
`config setup
conn %default
 type=tunnel
 left=%any
 leftid=EC2IP
 leftsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
 auto=add
 fragmentation=yes
 forceencaps=no
 mobike=yes
 leftauth=psk
 rightauth=psk

conn fb
 ike=aes256-sha-modp1024
 esp=aes256-sha1-modp1024
 right=%any
 rightsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
 rightdns=8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4
 ikelifetime=3600s
 keylife=3600s`

Comment: _rightsubnet_ is wrong, use the correct remote subnet (IKEv1 does not support narrowing). Did you change the FB's config too? Please update the question (configs, status, logs etc.).